# UnboundLocalError: local variable '' referenced before assignment python

Tags: python

estou com problema em passar o nome alterado caso o for chegue a determinado valor
CODIGO:

```
import threading
import time
from random import randint

def worker(message):
    f = open('addresses_0.csv', 'r')
    inicio = time.time()
    contador = 0
    for line in f:
        if contador >= 100000:
             lista = randint(0,9)
             return
        else:
            separa = line.split(',')
            dd = separa[0].strip().replace('"','')
            numero = separa[1].strip().replace('"','')
            print(lista)
            aprovadas = open('lista'+lista+'.txt', 'a')
            aprovadas.write('%s|%s\n' %(dd,numero))
            aprovadas.close()
            contador = contador+1

t = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=("thread sendo executada5",))
t.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bom primeiro você definiu a variável dentro do `if` é esta tento usa dentro de `else`
mais o `else` não consegue ensejar a variável dentro do `if` é só você tira a variável de dentro do `if`

é não precisa do else proque se ele chegar no if ele vai retorna false e não vai executar as próximas linhas espero ter ajudando

```
import threading
import time
from random import randint

def worker(message):
    f = open('addresses_0.csv', 'r')
    inicio = time.time()
    contador = 0
    for line in f:
        lista = randint(0,9) <----
        if contador >= 100000:
             return False
        
        separa = line.split(',')
        dd = separa[0].strip().replace('"','')
        numero = separa[1].strip().replace('"','')
        print(lista)
        aprovadas = open('lista'+lista+'.txt', 'a')
        aprovadas.write('%s|%s\n' %(dd,numero))
        aprovadas.close()
        contador = contador+1

t = threading.Thread(target=worker,args=("thread sendo executada5",))
t.start()
```